# Use sed to create email from old email

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a lot of emails that I would like changed to first initial and last name

```
example: Chris-lancer.chris@example.com
```

Is it possible to take the old email and replace it with

```
example: clancer@example.com
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
$ echo 'Chris-lancer.chris@example.com' | sed 's/^\([A-Z]\)[^-]*-\([^.]*\)\.[^@]*/\L\1\2/'
clancer@example.com
```

OR

```
$ echo 'example: Chris-lancer.chris@example.com' | sed 's/^\(example: \)\([A-Z]\)[^-]*-\([^.]*\)\.[^@]*/\1\L\2\3/'
example: clancer@example.com
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Avinash Raj this is what I was looking for because I will have multiple emails that I will be changing

Comment: What is the format in sed for the email Chris-lancer.chris@example.com? Like this is for a regular email address '[A-Za-z0-9._]+@[A-Za-z0-9.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}'?

Comment: you mean this `[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.\w{2,4}` . Use this regex in sed with `-r` parameter

Comment: When i use cat txt.txt | sed -r '[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.\w{2,4}' I get sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `['

Comment: you could use grep `echo 'example: Chris-lancer.chris@example.com' | grep -oP '[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.\w{2,4}'`

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i "s/Chris-lancer.chris/clancer/g" filename.txt
```

That will replace all occurences of "Chris-lancer.chris" with "clancer" in filename.txt.  Run it without the -i and it will just print the file without saving the changes.